# C++ const method returning non const pointer

Tags: c++

As an exercise in learning C++, I've created the following wrapper class which encapsulated the creation/destruction of a simple character buffer:

```
class BufferClass {
  private:
    char *mBufferPtr;
    
  public:
    BufferClass(int pSize)
      : mBufferPtr(new char[pSize]) {}
    
    virtual ~BufferClass() {
      delete[] mBufferPtr;
    }
    
    operator char*() {
      return mBufferPtr;
    }
    
    operator const char*() const {
      return mBufferPtr;
    }
};
```

If there was a circumstance where I wanted to create a const instance of this class (i.e. I have no intention of modifying the object once constructed), but had to use it in conjuction with a C API which only accepts non-const char* pointers (even thought it doesn't mutate the data), what's the general consensus on allowing the following:

```
operator char*() const {
  return mBufferPtr;
}
```

I realise I could just create a non-const instance of the Buffer class, but I'd be interested in comments regarding the validity of this approach.

Comment: `const` on the class object itself just means you can't modify the members. It doesn't mean you can't modify data that referenced by the members through pointers, unless you declare `const char *mBufferPtr;`

Comment: Note: You have  [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation on your hands.

Comment: An API that requires a `char*` pointer but doesn't modify those chars is flawed.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding the Rule of Three; I now see that copying/assigning an instance of this class would result in multiple delete[] calls on the same buffer. Thank you, that info is invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should design your class correctly. So, if this is a `const` member function, then it should not allow the object's data to be modified in any way. Compatibility with C API is not the responsibility of this class, so it should be resolved outside, if needed (`const_cast`'ing, copying to another buffer, etc).

Also, probably, you can write some wrapper for that C API:

- Use there correct constness in public interface and cast to required constness inside (if *really* required)
- Additionally make C++ interface if it will be more useful